# Perspective-projection matrix: how to calculate vertical FoV from just horizontal FoV and aspect-ratio?

Tags: opengl, 3d, matrix, projection-matrix, perspectivecamera

Consider the following perspective-projection matrix which works (perfectly fine) with just vertical-field-of-view and aspect-ratio given by the caller:

```
func (me *Mat4) Perspective (fovY, aspect, near, far float64) {
    tfY = near * math.Tan(fovY * math.Pi / 360)
    tfX = tfY * aspect
    me.Frustum(-tfX, tfX, -tfY, tfY, near, far)
}
```

How would one go about extending this function's body to support this: caller can now specify either vertical (fovY) or horizontal (fovX) field-of-view, but not both, and an aspect-ratio. How would this function be able to calculate the missing fovY from just the given aspect-ratio and fovX?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

1. Calculate width using horizontal FOV and distance to the near plane (hint: there's a right triangle with sides `near` and `width/2` and an angle `fovx/2`).
2. Calculate height using width and aspect ratio.
3. Calculate vertical FOV using height and distance to the near plane  (hint: there's a right triangle with sides `near` and `height/2` and an angle `fovy/2`).